# Adding Pivoting to the following Gauss Elimination code

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pivot

The program below uses gauss elimination to without pivoting. I would like to know how to add pivoting into this code to account for an array with a leading term of zero

```
from numpy import array,empty

A = array([[ 2, 1, 4, 1 ],
       [ 3, 4,-1,-1 ],
       [ 1, -4, 1, 5],
       [2,-2,1,3]],float)

v = array([ -4,3,9,7 ], float)
N = len(v)

for m in range (N):
    div = A[m,m]
    A[m,:] /= div
    v[m] /= div

for i in range(m+1,N):
    mult = A[i,m]
    A[i,:] -= mult*A[m,:]
    v[i] -= mult*v[m]

x = empty(N,float)
for m in range(N-1,-1,-1):
    x[m] = v[m]
    for i in range(m+1,N):
       x[m] -= A[m,i]*x[i]
```

the new array I would like it to solve is

```
A = array([[ 0, 1, 4, 1 ],
       [ 3, 4,-1,-1 ],
       [ 1, -4, 1, 5],
       [2,-2,1,3]],float)
```

Comment: Is this an algorithm question? It's not clear what the question is really...

Comment: My actual question is how to incorporate pivoting into the currently displayed algorithm for gauss elimination

Comment: What's wrong with [`scipy.linalg.lu`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html)?

Comment: @GarethRess I think he wanted to implemented his own version